# Bitcoin core datadir over NFS

Tags: bitcoin-core, datadir

I am going to run a bitcoin core on a Linux server (Ubuntu 20.04). I don't have enough storage to store blockchain data. Therefore, I want to save the data over an NFS server (CentOS release 6.10). However, I get an error when I set the `-datadir` to the shared folder.

The content of `/etc/exports` file in the NFS server (I've seen the configuration from [here](https://community.time4vps.com/discussion/224/kvm-ubuntu-configuring-nfs-server-and-nfs-client-sides/p1)):

```
/home/storage/  BITCOIN.CORE_IP(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

I mounted the remote shared directory in the Ubuntu 20.04 Linux server using the following command:

```
mount NFS_SERVER_IP:/home/storage/ /root/blockchain/
```

everything works fine, and the file system disk space usage report is: (`df -h`)

```
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
NFS_SERVER_IP:/home/storage/  1.0T  682M  1.0T   1% /root/blockchain
```

After running the following command to change the data directory to the shared directory:

```
./bitcoin-0.20.0/bin/bitcoind -datadir=/root/blockchain
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot obtain a lock on data directory /root/blockchain. Bitcoin Core is probably already running.
```

I should note that the shared directory is empty before running the bitcoind, then after that, it contains an empty file, which name is `.lock`. Moreover, If I set the `-datadir` to any local folder, it will not return any error!

Thanks.

Comment: Are you running bitcoind under a user with permission to write to that directory?

Comment: @RaghavSood I run the following command to see what user bitcoind is running as: ` ps -eo user,group,comm |egrep 'bitcoind' |awk '{print "Bitcoin user: " $1}' `
the result is: ` Bitcoin user: root `. I can mkdir and touch under the root user.

Comment: You might have another bitcoin instance running on the same machine, or on another machine connected to the same shared drive - try stopping all Bitcoin instance, deleting the `.lock` file (if it still exists), and then starting it again

Comment: @RaghavSood I have tried this multiple times, but nothing changes :((

Comment: Network file systems often don't support the same locking primitives that are expected from local filesystems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my view, we cannot move LevelDB index files such as chainstate, etc. to an external slow storage.

According to this [link](https://github.com/jimhashhq/bitcoin/blob/3c0377db483c50c5a9aecfc4684d6329951a1c7c/doc/file-partition.md), we should only move the `blkxxxxx.dat` and `revxxxxx.dat` files to an external storage. These files are inside `${datadir}/blocks/` by default. Since the `index` directory (`${datadir}/blocks/index`) contains high i/o-frequency LevelDB index files, moving it to an external storage will increase the initial blockchain synchronization time.

So take the following steps (I followed the instructions of the [link](https://github.com/jimhashhq/bitcoin/blob/3c0377db483c50c5a9aecfc4684d6329951a1c7c/doc/file-partition.md)):

1. run bitcoind.

> Let it run for a few minutes, or long enough that it has started synchronizing [[ref]](https://github.com/jimhashhq/bitcoin/blob/3c0377db483c50c5a9aecfc4684d6329951a1c7c/doc/file-partition.md)

2. Then kill the bitcoind.
3. Next, Move the "index" folder up one level (so that it may remain on the local storage):

```
mv -f ~/.bitcoin/blocks/index ~/.bitcoin/
```

4. Move the blocks folder to the shared directory:

```
mv -f ~/.bitcoin/blocks ~/blockchain/
```

5. Create a symbolic (soft) link to the local index directory at blocks directory in the shared storage (*use absolute path*):

```
ln -s /root/.bitcoin/index /root/blockchain/blocks/index
```

6. Now, create a symbolic (soft) link to the blocks directory at .bitcoin in the local storage (*again use absolute path*)::

```
ln -s /root/blockchain/blocks/ /root/.bitcoin/blocks
```